# React: store array objects in state and display with keys

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm learning react and I want to know the correct way to store object arrays in state and then access them later, or if it is correct and if I should do this at all.

In react I perform and AJAX request and I get a list of objects. These I want to store in state so that I can push it to another react class as a props. I want to be able to access the items in the objects.

**UPDATE** - fixed and working

```
var Providers = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {providers: []};
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        var uri = this.props.source;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: uri,
            crossDomain: true,
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            var newProviders = []
            $.each(data, function (i, p) {
                newProviders.push(data[i]);
            });
            console.log(newProviders);
            this.setState({ providers: newProviders });

        }.bind(this))
        .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(textStatus);
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Provider providers={this.state.providers}></Provider>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Provider = React.createClass({
    componentDidUpdate: function () {
        console.log(this.props.providers[0]);
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <p></p>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is most likely working, but I suspect that your understanding of [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) is incorrect. `componentDidMount` is called only once, after the component is initially rendered. It is not called when props are updated.

You may want to look into [componentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate).

In general, I would avoid using custom objects for state - especially shared mutable objects - and use plain objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't setState with each element in array because it will do one terrible thing - rerender component each time. Which will result in terrible performance later id it will become big app.

I would suggest to setState already prepared data so it wouldnt needlesly rerender [i] Times. So setState only once in Ajax requests if you can